# Explain the association relationships with the Block in the diagram, see image

Tags: rhapsody, sysml

Please check the attached figure. I have block A, inside this block I added the block B and constraint property C, in addition outside the block I 
have constraint property D. I insert all of them in a BDD to see their relationships with A. It can be seen that B appears with a containtment relationship, however C does not but it does appear as part. I added a composite relationship with D and appears as part but in this case with different symbol.

Why C does not appear with a containment relationship if I added it inside A.
And why the difference of symbol of the parts of A? Can you give me the meaning as is presented in the diagram. For instance: block B is contained by A, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The concepts are clarified by experts in the following link.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!topic/sysmlforum/bI3ncpkkFBo